# Can't share Documents Folder in win 10

Tags: windows-10, network-shares

I want to share my Documents folder. When I share it using File Explorer the resulting share is called "Users" and the path is C:\users

What I want is C:\users\username\documents only.

I don't remember this being a problem in XP or 7.

I running win 10 1607 and a work network.

Is this a feature, bug or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `net share name="C:\users\username\documents" /full` from a `cmd` shell?

Comment: I hadn't but I have now. Had to change it slightly /Full fails. I used:

Comment: @DavidPostill
Oops, timed out!
I hadn't but I have now. Had to change it slightly /Full fails. I used:
net share sharename=C:\users\username\documents /GRANT:user1,FULL /GRANT:user2,FULL